# how can I use the function of groupby by Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use the function like groupby by Flutter and firebase.

But I cannot find how to do it...

I coded but I am not sure

To be:

[image]

I want to calculate each category and make table like this

自重：　3
ジム：　2

here is code

workout.dart

```
class Workout {

  Workout(DocumentSnapshot doc) {

    this.documentReference = doc.reference;

    this.title = doc.data()['title'];
    this.count = doc.data()['count'].toString();
    this.item = doc.data()['category'].toString();
    final Timestamp timestamp = doc.data()['createdAt'];
    this.createdAt = timestamp.toDate();
  }

  String title;
  String count;
  String item;
  DateTime createdAt;
  bool isDone = false;
  DocumentReference documentReference;

}
```

model.dart

```
Map<String, String> Categorylist = {};
Future getCategory() async {
    final documents = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('workoutlist')
        .where('category', isEqualTo: 'ジム')
        .get();

  }
```

main.dart

"I have no idea how to code it"

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have any SQL-like ability to perform aggregations.  It does not support grouping like you ask.  What you will have to do is make a query, iterate the query results, and perform the grouping and counting in that loop.